# Is there a way to save the pid of a windows service in a var?

Tags: batch-file, service

I want to make a batch file that check if BITS service is stopped or not.
While it's stopped, it start it and set priority to BITS service by PID with a loop. Can anyone help me ?

```
net start BITS
for /f "tokens=3" %A in ('sc queryex BITS ^| find "PID"') do wmic service where "ProcessID=%A" get caption,name,processid /value
 IF "!pid!" NEQ "0" (
  wmic process where processid= %A% CALL setpriority "realtime"
 )
```

Comment: You have posted some code inside your post, can you tell us what it's there for? Is that the script you've written to perform the task you've laid out above it? If so please explain what the issue is with it, or its result? This site isn't here to review your code, we expect you to tell us enough information for us to help you fix it.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you're treating a service as a process and what your reason is for wanting its priority to be set to realtime anyhow.

Comment: yes to start BITS the command is "net start BITS" but I would make a batch that make what I described before. I'm sorry of my bad english and I don't learn batch at all so I was asking her for some piece of code. And I want to start BITs and set priority to realtime for a game to run better because of connection. And the problem is to set priority of a process by getting the service PID because we can't set service priority under Windows because BITS is hosted by svchost instance but there are many svchost.

Comment: `1)` A single instance of `svchost` process can host multiple services; by setting the priority for the `svchost` process that is hosting the BITS service, You will set the priority for **all of the services** which are hosted by that particular instance of `svchost`. `2)` Connection performance is affected by the factors like network connection quality, response time, bandwidth,.. not by the process priority. But at the end it is up to you to decide what should be done with the obtained `PID`: just displaying it, killing the process, doing something useful/harmful/useless,...

Comment: But as I understood, your main issue is that you have difficaulty to save the `PID` in a variable and use it afterwards (for whatever purpose). In that case I suggest you to reword your question to focus on the main issue you have.

Comment: Thank you I changed the title